# Retaining Group Permissions with a Git Pull

Tags: git

I have a user:group owned by www-data. Whenever I do a pull to the server (in the cgi-bin directory), the modified files get changed from www-data to root.

I would like to know if there is a way to pull the content of the files from git while at the same time keep the user-group permissions unchanged after the pull has been executed.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Git does nothing special about user and group ownership and permissions, except to set or clear the `x` bit based on the mode listed for each file as stored in the repository.  This means you configure these things using the usual system configuration items.  These vary by OS, but Solaris and Linux both use the convention that new files are owned by the group of the process that creates the file *unless* the g+s (group-sticky) bit is set on the *containing directory*.  The g+s bit is inherited when creating subdirectories, so it suffices to set it on existing directories once.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was the solution I eventually resorted to. I saw people made mention of git cache-meta but the steps to implementing it were not clear. My only concern with g+s is that it only retains the group permissions and not the owner. The code base is something I inherited and some of the permissions  that the group must be given may have been set to the owner. I may have to modify these and set the permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are pulling as root.  You would want to pull as the user intended to own the files.  Of course, attaching credentials to your `www-data` account is not great for security, so you should probably use something like github's deploy keys (can pull code, but not push).

If you want to pull as `www-data`, you can `su - www-data`, but initially you will have problems since root already owns files and parts of the git index.  You will want to `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/dir` so that your intended user can modify the repo and index during pulls.

Also you can use the sticky bit as suggested in comment.